# How to check values before update in Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

When using updating via `Eloquent` it returns affected rows as a result. Is it possible somehow to get status of update? For example if I passing some bad id in `WHERE` it still return 0 affected rows, though here I need to know that this id does not exist. Basically when the user clicks a save button, but nothing edit - I get 0 affected rows from Eloquent and also when bad id is entered. I need to somehow separate this things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check first if the `WHERE` returns anything:

```
if(Model::where($where)->count() > 0){
    // row(s) found > do update
}
else {
    // where doesn't match any rows
}
```